# Java 8 stream group entries by numerical proximity

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of unix timestamps such as:

```
[1111111 1200000 1200060 1200120 1200180 1300000 1400000 140060]
```

I want to group them by clusters of which are within 60 seconds of each other with the key being the first timestamp, such as:

```
{1111111=[1111111], 1200000=[1200000,120060, 1200120], 1300000=[1300000], 1400060=[1400000, 1400060]}
```

I have achieved this by using a for loop, and I was hoping there was a better way of doing this preferably using Java 8 streams.

(I am not great with Java and so if there isn't a way to use a stream, is there a better to structure the for-loop?)

```
List <Integer> timestamps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
timestamps.add(1111111);
timestamps.add(1200000);
timestamps.add(1200060);
timestamps.add(1200120);
timestamps.add(1200180);
timestamps.add(1300000);
timestamps.add(1400000);
timestamps.add(1400060);

HashMap <Integer, List <Integer>> grouped = new HashMap<Integer, List <Integer>>();

List <Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < timestamps.size(); i++) {
  if(i > 0 && (timestamps.get(i - 1) + 60 < timestamps.get(i))) {
        grouped.put(subList.get(0), new ArrayList <Integer>(subList));
        subList.removeAll(subList);
   }
   subList.add(timestamps.get(i));  
}
grouped.put(subList.get(0), subList);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do this operation, you need to operate on consecutive elements on the Stream matching a predicate. Unfortunately, there is no standard way to easily achieve that currently with the Stream API.

The StreamEx library provides this facility with the `groupRuns` operation. Considering the list is already sorted (otherwise, you can sort it by calling `sorted()`), you can have:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =
    StreamEx.of(timestamps)
            .groupRuns((t1, t2) -> t2 - t1 <= 60)
            .toMap(l -> l.get(0), l -> l);
```

Result with the data in your question:

```
{1200000=[1200000, 1200060, 1200120, 1200180], 1300000=[1300000], 1400000=[1400000, 1400060], 1111111=[1111111]}
```

The method [`groupRuns`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) groups all consecutive elements that match the given predicate and collects all those element into a `List` by default. In this case, the first element of the list will be the key of the final Map and the list itself will be the value.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had the opportunity to try out this library yet, but I can see it does exactly what is needed.

Comment: Pity the stream API doesn't support it